# Function to store strings as ints

Tags: python, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I have a fixed 32 bits in which to store as much DNA as possible. The amount of space required to store 1 character of DNA (`'A'`, `'C'`, `'G'` or `'T'`) is 2 bits (`00`, `01`, `10`, `11`, as there are only 4 combinations).

To store *up to 2* characters, (so, `A`, `C`, `G`, `T`, `AA`, `AC`, ..., `GG`) there are 20 possible combinations, which we can work out with the function `((4**(x+1))-2)/(4-1)`, where `x` is the maximum length of DNA we want to store. 16 characters of DNA would therefore have 5,726,623,060 combinations, however in 32 bits I can only store up to 4,294,967,296 numbers (2**32).

So long story short, in 32 bits the maximum amount of variable-length DNA one can store is 15 letters (1,431,655,764 combinations).

So, next step is to make a function which takes up to 15 letters of DNA as a string, and turns it into a number. It doesn't matter which number (`'A'` could be `0`, it could be `1`, it could be `1332904`, it really doesn't matter) so long as we can reverse the function and get the number back to `'A'` later.

I started to solve this by making a dictionary of `key, value` pairs containing 1,431,655,764 elements, but quickly ran out of RAM. This is why I need a translation function from string to int.

Comment: Once having established that you can store each character in two bits, I am not sure what part you are having difficulty with. Do you have any code?

Comment: 2 bits per letter only works when the length of the string is constant.
For example, in 4 bits I can represent 'AA' with 0000, but i cannot represent 'A' on its own. There are 20 combinations of DNA, and only 16 values can be stored in 4 bits.

Comment: In that case you have extra information (i.e. the length of the string) which will require extra space to be encoded.

Comment: "Why would you down vote and a submit a close vote for a post with no previous solution and no reason why!?" because your question boils down to "give me the codez"

Comment: @khelwood - I thought i mentioned that when i wrote "UP TO" in all caps, and then provided a list of example strings...
AdamSmith - dont all questions tagged under a programming language boil down to that? I'll take a hint of a solution if you have one! Also i said that i tried making a lookup table in a dictionary, and other than that i literally have no idea where to even start, which is why i came here...

Comment: @J.J khelwood already gave you that. encode the length of the string followed by your bytes of ACGT.

Comment: Mostly this is a silly proposition because you're trying to use Python in a very memory-limited context. That's a bad idea for all the same reasons that you don't use watercolors for paint by numbers. It gets sloppy. Use a language that doesn't do its own memory management

Comment: I would need 4 bits to encode the length, meaning there is only have 28 bits to encode the DNA. 28 bits can hold up to 268435456, or 13 letters of DNA. I would rather do it another way and store all 15 characters.

Comment: Note that the `""` takes 25 bytes in Python and `0` takes 12 bytes. It's not known for having the smallest memory footprint :)

Comment: Python has numpy, and that is just as efficient as anything else at storing 32 bit unsigned ints. Im not sure where all this hostility towards a fairly simply question is coming from, haha, but theres really no need to bring Python into this ;)

Comment: @DSM yeah in retrospect I agree. Nominated for reopening

Comment: Are you're representing a single sequence with *multiple* of these 32-bit representations with 2bits reserved? If so, note that for sequences of more than a few hundred bases it uses less memory to store the length separately, and just stuff 16 bases in each 32-bit area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my suggestion.

If storing your letters takes 2 to 30 bits, you have at least 2 bits left to help you to deduce the length. Always add a `1` after the bits representing your characters, and pad the rest with zeroes. That way, if you look for the **last `1`** in your bit pattern, it will always be just after the end of your string.

E.g.

```
A  -> 00 (meaning 'A') followed by 1 (meaning 'end') followed by 29 zeroes
   -> 00100000000000000000000000000000
C  -> 01 (meaning 'C') followed by 1 (meaning 'end') followed by 29 zeroes
   -> 01100000000000000000000000000000
G  -> 10 (meaning 'G') followed by 1 (meaning 'end') followed by 29 zeroes
   -> 10100000000000000000000000000000
T  -> 11 (meaning 'T') followed by 1 (meaning 'end') followed by 29 zeroes
   -> 11100000000000000000000000000000
AA -> 0000 (meaning 'AA') followed by 1, followed by 27 zeroes
   -> 00001000000000000000000000000000
...
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
   -> 000000000000000000000000000000 (meaning the 'A's) followed by 1, followed by 1 zero
   -> 00000000000000000000000000000010
```

That ought to unambiguously represent your string and allow you up to 15 characters in 32 bits.

Answer (score 2):

Given a static ordering, you can refer to each individual permutation as a single number representing its order in the sequence. Then rather than building the dictionary you can convert it on the other side.

```
import itertools

def build_sequence(length):
    return itertools.product("ACTG", repeat=length)

def encode(sequence: str):
    seq = build_sequence(len(str))
    t_seq = list(sequence)  # to compare to seq
    for idx, s in enumerate(seq):
        if s == t_seq:
            return idx

def decode(e_sequence):
    max_length = math.ceil(math.log(e_sequence, 4))
    # max_length is the character count of ATCGs that e_sequence contains,
    #   since each sequence has 4**length elements
    seq = build_sequence(max_length)
    for _ in range(e_sequence):
        # skipping these is like indexing a list
        next(seq)
    return next(seq)
```

You can then pack that number into a smaller type and send it over the wire, unpack it again, and decode it.

```
import struct

packed = struct.pack("I", encode(some_sequence))
#  send it? I'm not sure what you're doing with it

rcvd_pack = b'SUUU'
unpacked = struct.unpack("I", rcvd_pack)
# becomes a tuple of the value
enc_seq = unpacked[0]

result = decode(enc_seq)
```

This should let you build 16 character sequences and pack them in 32 bits of data.

Comment: Thank you for this Adam, i learnt a lot from figuring out how your code works :)
Im putting it into a numpy array, but yeah id use struct exactly as you described. The only thing is that as you walk through the itertools.product, to encode 15 G's takes a very long time. But it does work, and is elegant. the math.ceil(math.log(seq,4)) was the secret sauce for me :)

Comment: @J.J agreed, it does. You should be able to math your way there, but I don't have the time to figure out how the cases work. It'll be something similar to your binary encoding, but in base 4 instead of base 2 (I think? I'm fuzzy on the math)

Answer (score 1):

Using Khelwood's info, I solved it with the following code:

```
b = {'A':0b00,'C':0b01,'G':0b10,'T':0b11}
t = {'00':'A','01':'C','10':'G','11':'T'}

def binarize(string):
    result = 0
    for char in (string + 'G').ljust(16,'A'): result = (result << 2) + d[char]
    return result

def textualize(value):
    result = ''
    for twobits in [ format(value, '032b')[i:i+2] for i in range(0,32,2) ]:
        result += t[twobits]
    return result.rstrip('A')[:-1]

>>> binarize('TTTTTTTTTTTTTTT')
    4294967294

>>> textualize(4294967294)
    u'TTTTTTTTTTTTTTT'
```

I'm sure there is a more efficient way of doing all this, which I think I will need to do as i'll be encoding and decoding billions of times, but for now it at least works :)